# Safari autofill multiple e-mail adresses

Tags: safari, email, contacts

My personal vCard has multiple email addresses. When I use the autofill feature from Safari I always get the wrong email address filled into the web form. How can I get Safari autofill to use the right email address?

Answer (score 1):

It will default to the first email address in the list, so put the one you want to use for autofill first in your address book and it will then use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Safari's too dumb to select the first on the list.

You have to create a new card with ONLY the info you want to be autofilled & designate that card "Me"

Or, change to Opera browser which enables you to nominate multiple entries for multiple fields, then presents them as Drop-Down Lists. Simples.